# HttpClient PutAsync to update a field using RestAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, api, asp.net-web-api

We have a third party API which has both the GET and PUT methods on it.The third party API returns response and accepts only in XML. The api looks like `https://bh.org/api/v2/prj/A152` with the GET it returns

```
<prj:prj uri="https://bh.org/api/v2/prj/V51" lid="V51" xmlns:udf="http://ge.com/ri/userdefined" xmlns:ri="http://ge.com/ri" xmlns:file="http://ge.com/ri/file" xmlns:prj="http://ge.com/ri/prj">
<name>fgfgfg</name>
<res uri="https://bh.org/api/v2/res/19"/>
<udf:type name="cis"/>
<udf:field type="String" name="ST">Cli</udf:field>
<udf:field type="String" name="CPN">TestName</udf:field>
<udf:field type="Numeric" name="No">1</udf:field>
<udf:field type="String" name="CA">Do not know</udf:field>
<udf:field type="String" name="Cto">Me</udf:field>
<udf:field type="String" name="Site">GT</udf:field>
</prj:prj>
```

I need to change the name here from ad-93 to ABCD using the put method in third party API. I have created applications where we call the third party API using GET method to get the response

```
 using (var client_Name = new HttpClient())
 {
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
  Uri uri = new Uri(BaseURL_C);
  client_Name.BaseAddress = uri;
  client_Name.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
  client_Name.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
  client_Name.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new   System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray_C));

  string c_URL = BaseURL_C + "api/v2/prj/" + Name;
  var response_LabURL = client_Name.GetAsync(c_URL).Result;
  string responseString_URL = response_LabURL.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  XDocument new_doc = XDocument.Parse(responseString_URL);
  new_doc.Descendants("name").FirstOrDefault().Value = serviceResponse;
```

With the above code the I am able to change the value of the name in the XDocument that I retrieved as response. Now I am trying to pass the XDocument as a parameter to the putAsync to upadte the field using the Rest API.

```
 using (var putClient = new HttpClient())
 {
 var requestUrl = string c_URL = BaseURL_C + "api/v2/prj/" + Name;;
 using (HttpContent httpContent = new XDocument(new_doc))
  {
    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PutAsync(requestUrl, httpContent).Result;
  }
```

But the above code throws error like `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent'`

I am not sure how to covert the XDocument new_doc in to HtppContent so to pass them as parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use it something like this

```
HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(new_doc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
```

and remove the line

```
httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");
```